# What is the difference between 2 code of Listview adapter getView method

Tags: android, listview

I know recycle view is new but I want to know what is difference in 2 codes in list view. I have already tried to search a lot but not get specific answer. I know First one is more faster then the second because of memory consumption but why second code is slow then the first one what is the internal process can any one enplane it.

This is the first Code

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


 final HashMap<String ,String > item = lst.get(position);
            ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.shadow_request_row, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            viewHolder.msg = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.title.setText(item.get(Const.USERNAME));
        viewHolder.msg.setText(item.get(Const.GET_MESSAGE));
        return convertView;
   }
```

This is the Second Code

```
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 final HashMap<String ,String > item = lst.get(position);
            ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.shadow_request_row, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            viewHolder.msg = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);

        }
        viewHolder.title.setText(item.get(Const.USERNAME));
        viewHolder.msg.setText(item.get(Const.GET_MESSAGE));
        return convertView;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second example is missing the part about saving the `viewHolder` as the tag of the created view if the view is just being inflated and reusing the `viewHolder` if the view already exists.

Answer (score 0):

List View items are re created whenever it wants. (This happens when you scroll up and down). Whenever a `ListView` needs to re create an item it calls the `getView()` of the adapter with the required position. Inside the `getView()` method you have the logic to generate the item `View` required for that position.

The method `findViewById()` that you use to find a `View` inside the XML, is CPU extensive. You might see a considerable lag if your XML contains a long sequence of children and the `getView()` contains lots of `findViewById()` calls.

This is where a ViewHolder comes handy. A ViewHolder is a class that can hold the View items. You can use the already created ViewHolder objects instead of calling `findViewById()` every time.

To make use of this you have to save a ViewHolder object associated with a particular position. You do it like this.

```
ViewHolder viewHolder;
if(convertView==null){
   //the view is created for the first time
   //you have to make the View HOlder object here
   viewHOlder=new ViewHOlder(convertView);
   //ViewHOlder constructor can find the required view elements and store it in variables
   //now you have to save this View Holder object for future reference
   //you save it as a tag
   convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
}
```

Now you have a defined View Holder for the specific item position. Here is how to re use it.
When the `ListView` adapter wnats to re use it the `convertView` given to `getItem()` is not null. So the re use occurs in the `else` statement of the above `if`.

```
else{
   //you already have a pre created View holder. Retrieve it.
   viewHOlder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
   //now you can get access to your View elements easily
}
```

In you second example, you create the ViewHOlder but you never re use it. So it makes not improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your very detail answer Malith Lakshan but my query about this video please watch it in this video they are saying both codes are right but I couldn't understand why first one is faster. Please watch this one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70